# Javascript encodeURI returns unexpected value

Tags: javascript, php, url-encoding

I have a problem URL-encoding a text with javascript.
I am in Germany, where we have these "Umlaute" (ÄÖÜ), and these letters make some problems.

An online encoder/decoder returned the following results for the word "Äpfel" (apples).

Äpfel >>> url-encode >>> %C3%84pfel

%C3%84pfel >>> url-decode >>> Äpfel

For testing, I created the following php.file (poc.php) with no php-content, just the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var t = "Äpfel";
    t = encodeURI(t);
    alert(t);
    t = decodeURI(t);
    alert(t);
</script>
```

The first alert returns "%EF%BF%BDpfel", which differs from the result of the online encoder.

The second alert returns "�pfel" (yes, the diamond with the "?").

It seems that javascript cannot decode the text it just encoded.

I guess the cause of this behaviour is somewhere in the PHP settings. When I just rename the file from "poc.php" to "poc.html" the encoding is correct and the alerts return the same results as the online encoder/decoder.

When I check the current encoding, javascript and php return "utf-8".

In my "real" project I have a ".js" file included in my php-file (with the same problem).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/functions.js"></script>
```

Has anybody an idea what causes this behaviour?

Comment: Make sure your source code is UTF-8 and that that's how it's being delivered to the clients. You can use the browser developer tools "Network" tab to examine the response headers to verify that your server is using the correct `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weird byte stream %EF%BF%BD you're receiving is utf-8 version of the Unicode replacement character, that is, literally the � symbol.

The Javascript portion can url-decode the text it just url-encoded, it was just asked to encode the symbol for a missing symbol.

So: some part of your system is not using utf-8, but some other character set instead, and there's an unnecessary conversion done. My guess is that the file is encoded in latin-1, aka. ISO 8859-1, and PHP tries to read it as if it was UTF-8, converting the unrecognized character 0xc4 ('Ä' in latin-1) to the replacament character symbol.

Comment: Hi Niko and many thanks for your reply. The encoding of the file was wrong indeed. I opened the php file with notepad++ an it showed me that the encoding was "ANSI". I changed that to "UTF-8", saved the file an it worked.